# return list after sorting with repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, list, repeater

I have a list going into a repeater, sorting with jquery sortable(), and then need to put the sorted list into a session variable. I cannot seem to figure out how to get the sorted values back into a list.

Html code:

```
<div>
<asp:Repeater ID="LstSortable" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul id="sortable">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <%# Container.DataItem %>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

</div>
```

page load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'create test array
    Dim order As New List(Of String)
    order.Add("Item1")
    order.Add("Item2")
    order.Add("Item3")
    order.Add("Item4")

    'testing repeater
    LstSortable.DataSource = order

    LstSortable.DataBind()

End Sub
```

button press to put sorted list into session variable:

This is the code I am playing with, it currently does not work:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim orderBy As New List(Of String)

    Dim count As Integer
    For count = 0 To LstSortable.Items.Count - 1 Step count + 1
        Dim chk As ListItem = CType(LstSortable.Items(count).FindControl(LstSortable.ID), ListItem)
    Next

    Session("OrderBy") = orderBy

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

This is using vb.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by creating an array of li elements using jquery and then passing them to a webservice using an ajax call.

I had to enable sessions in the web service:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
```

Then I parsed the array into a string and placed in the session variable.

jquery:

```
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            placeholder: "vacant",
            update: function(e, ui) {

                //create vars  
                var orderArray = [], wrap = {};

                $("#sortable li").each(function(i) {

                    var imgObj = $(this).text();
                    //alert(imgObj);
                    //add object to array  
                    orderArray.push(imgObj);
                });

                //wrap in object  
                wrap.d = orderArray;

                //pass to server  
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../WebService.asmx/updateOrder",
                    data: JSON.stringify(wrap),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data.d === "saved") {
                            alert("success");
                        } else {
                            alert("fail");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xmlHttpRequest, status, err) {
                        alert("This has error: " + err);
                    }

                });

            }
        });
```

web service:

```
Public Class WebService
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
Public Function updateOrder(ByVal d As String()) As String

    'process JSON object  
    Dim orderBy As String
    Dim str As String
    orderBy = New String(" Order By ")
    For Each str In d
        'define procedure  
        orderBy += str
    Next

    Session("OrderBy") = orderBy

    'success!  
    Return "saved"

End Function

End Class
```